# unexpected space between Elements in UltimateRecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, view, android-recyclerview

i´m using the UlimateRecyclerView which extends the RecyclerView with a lot of features. It should be used like the normal RecyclerView as said on GitHub.

When Run the Code, there is a big space between the elements, i don´t know why...

I hope you can help!

Screenshot of Problem
[UltimateRecyclerView Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljDqx.png)

My XML with ultimateRecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sherzad.recyclerviewuebung.MainActivity">

    <com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ultimate_recyclerView"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView;
import com.yqritc.recyclerviewflexibledivider.HorizontalDividerItemDecoration;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    UltimateRecyclerView dhikrListe;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dhikrListe = (UltimateRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ultimate_recyclerView);

        dhikrListe.setHasFixedSize(true);
        dhikrListe.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this)); //Hier könnten wir auch verschiedene Layouts festlegen. Bei der ListView, die vorher hatten, ist das Linearlayout fest eingestellt.

        dhikrListe.addItemDecoration(
                new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(this)
                        .color(Color.GRAY)
                        .build()); // Der Divider trennt die Zeilen mit einem Strich

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);

        dhikrListe.setAdapter(myAdapter); //Adapter wird gesetzt


    }
}
```

My Model/Object

```
public class Dhikr {

    private int id;
    private String text = "";

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Dhikr(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

My Adapter

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateDifferentViewTypeAdapter;
import com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView;
import com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder;
import com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateViewAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by sherzad on 20.11.16.
 */

public class MyAdapter extends UltimateViewAdapter{

    List<Dhikr> dhikrListe;
    private MainActivity activity;

    public MyAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity){
        this.activity = mainActivity;

        dhikrListe = new ArrayList<Dhikr>();
        dhikrListe.add(new Dhikr("Hello!"));
        dhikrListe.add(new Dhikr("yess!"));


    }

    public static class DhikrViewHolder extends UltimateRecyclerviewViewHolder{
        public TextView dhikrText;

        public DhikrViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            dhikrText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }

    @Override //Hier wird das Layout vorbereitet und geladen
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = this.activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dhikr, parent, false);
        return new DhikrViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder newFooterHolder(View view) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHeaderHolder(View view) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }

    //Hier werden die Daten befüllt
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Dhikr dhikr = dhikrListe.get(position);

        DhikrViewHolder dhikrHolder = (DhikrViewHolder) holder; //Wir wandeln den holder (der in dieser methode übergeben wird) in unseren eigenen TodoViewHolder um, um auf seine Eigenschaften (todoTitel) zugreifen zu können und im nächsten Schritt ihn zu setzen.
        dhikrHolder.dhikrText.setText(dhikr.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateHeaderViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dhikrListe.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getAdapterItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long generateHeaderId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: make your row layout that is R.layout.dhikr wrap_content instead of match_parent

Comment: WORKED !!!! Thanks a lot!! i was a lot frustrated because of this issue...understanding the recyclerView itself takes time...so now the next step is ready to go: realizing swipe-delete!

Comment: Glad it helped you.